# iphone server communication

Tags: php, iphone, communication

I am really confused about all the different kinds of servers and iphone-server communications  etc.

I would like to know which would be the best way to implement the following:

If the app starts on the iphone it calls a function or a script on a server with a parameter (for example: the UDID of the iphone). Then the server creates a folder with the string of the UDID as the name of the folder. If this folder already exist (if the iphone already used the app) it checks some other stuff and send some data back to the iphone (for example if an image is in the folder, show this image on the iphone).

I already read a lot of stuff but I have no idea what to use. Could you please give me some keywords or classes I should look up. Any tips on what kind of server I should use would be appreciated.

On a side note I guess sending the UDID should be secure because it is sensitive user-data...

Well I hope you can help me a bit.

thx. Maxi

Answer (score -1):

When you talk about a server it can be confusing. You can have server as hardware and server as an application. If you already have hardware server and a site that can receive information through lets say POST. You can use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to simply upload information about the device. One thing you have to think about is that you cannot collect UUID. Apple does not allow you to collect this number unless you are an ad company that serves ads. What you can do is to send hash like md5 of the UUID and use this for your catalog names.

Comment: Why do you think apple doesn't permit collection of UDID? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier mentions certain best practices around using UDID wisely, but does not prohibit use